# Writing the equation of a function from its plot

Tags: homework

> Write the equation of the function graphed here, leave in factored form

[image: plot]

I think it would be a cosine function, but the way it's shifted to the left makes me question that. I also don't know what "leave in factored form" means.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Comment: The two arrow heads at the ends of curve very likely indicate the curve goes off to -∞ on the left and to +∞ on the right. So the curve is not periodic. Therefore, not a cosine. I think you are looking at a cubic polynomial.

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you want to use the software *Mathematica* for this problem so that it can be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

The roots of the cubic equation occur at $x = \{ -2, 1, 3 \}$ so

$$ f(x) = a (x+2)(x-1)(x-3) $$

where you adjust $a$ to give you the value $f(0) = 3$, all taken from your graph.

Can you finish this task?